# What is meant by writing $J = L + S$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum

In the fine structure of atoms, one often writes the total angular momentum $\vec{J}$ as a sum of the orbital and spin angular momenta. $$\vec{J} = \vec{L} + \vec{S}$$ I would have thought that means that for all components $i = \{x, y, z\}$,
$$J_i = L_i + S_i$$

and so e.g. for the Zeeman effect Hamiltonian $H_{Z} =  \omega_L(L_z + 2 S_z) =^? \omega_L(J_z + S_z)$.

However, I have been told by authoritative sources that this reasoning is incorrect.
If so, what *is* the meaning of the vector equation above?

Comment: I'm not sure about your authoritative sources, i think it is true that $J_i = L_i+S_i$.

Comment: The source was my professor on an assignment. I was a touch confused by the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

On the one hand, $\hat{J}_i=\hat{L}_i+\hat{S}_i$ is correct; in other words, any ket $|\psi\rangle$ satisfies $\hat{J}_i|\psi\rangle=\hat{L}_i|\psi\rangle+\hat{S}_i|\psi\rangle$. On the other hand, because $\hat{L}_i,\,\hat{S}_i$ have different eigenkets, you can't in general just add their spectra to get the eigenvalues of $\hat{J}_i$.

Comment: I don't understand this response. I agree with the first sentence but I am having trouble following the second sentence. Could you please expand? If, for example,  there is no spin-orbit coupling or other higher order effects and you are considering some one-electron atomic hamiltonian, then L and S commute with the Hamiltonian and therefore have share common eigenkets.